# How to get the max value from an array in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have an input source as follows. What I want to do is capture the numeric value on each of the `Layer` lines into an array and then print out the maximum value.

#### input

```
MACRO cell_1
 size 0.1 by 0.1 ; 

 pin a
 (....same topology as pin vcc)
 END a

 pin b
 (.....same topology as pin vcc)
 END b

 Pin vcc
  aaaa
  bbbb
  Port
   Layer m2 ;
  END
  CCC
  DDD
  Port 
   Layer m1 ;
  END
  EEE
  FFF
  Port
   Layer m0 ;
  END
 END vcc

 pin d
 (....same topology as pin vcc)
 END d
END cell_1

MACRO cell_2
(repeated)
END cell_2
```

#### my code:

```perl
foreach my $file ( @files ) {   # @files = multiple path  of abc/def/fgh/cell_lef

    open( INFILE, "<$file" ) || die "Can not open stdcell_file\n";
    my @lines = <INFILE>;
    close INFILE;

    $init = 1;
    $delimiter =~ /^$/;      # between each MACRO. haven't utilize this yet

    foreach (@lines) {

        if ( $init ) {
            $path = 1;
            $init = 0;
            @num  = ();
        }

        if ( $path ) {

            if ( /MACRO\s+(\S+) /) {
                $cellname = $1; print "$cellname\n";
            }

            if ( /SIZE\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)/ ) {
                $footprint_x = $1;
                $footprint_y = $3;
                print "$footprint_x $footprint_y\n";
            }

            if ( /PIN vcc/ .. /END vcc/ ) {

                #grab the highest value from layer (m*)
                #print "max layer = m*"
            }

            $init = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

#### intended output

```
cell_1
0.1 0.1
m2

cell_2
0.2 0.2
m3
```

#### The code I am attempting to use:

```
if ( /PIN vcc/../END vcc/ ) {
    if ( /LAYER\s+m(\S+) / ) {
        push(@num, $1);
        print "@num";
    }                               
}
```

The problem with my code so far is that when I print the value of `@num`, all the values are joined together as a string (`210`) instead of individual elements: `2 1 0` — so I am not able to do the sorting to get the max value.

***Update***: I am not sure how to integrate the `while` into my code as I'm using foreach as my main loop

Comment: The nested if statements are a bit awkward but this should work. The formatting - `print join " ", @num;`  might help - shouldn't affect the sorting (which you don't show).

Comment: In your output, where does the line "0.2 0.2" come from?

Comment: @marty , it is not reflected in the input source. it's just a random number to illustrate what my intended output looks like

Comment: Your `print "@num"` is the problem. That's how Perl prints arrays. Go into debug mode and do this to view the @num array: `x @num`. It will print one line per array item.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is capturing the numbers ok, it's just that you're printing the whole array.  Perl's default separator for array elements when you print an array is `""` ie, nothing - so, it looks like a single string but it's three (or however many) elements printed next to each other without a separator.

You can iterate over input line by line in Unix filter style with `while (<>) {`.  You can switch on a "scanning mode" flag when "PIN vcc" is found and switch it off when "END vcc" is found.  After that, use a regex to search for the layer line but always use 'extended mode' `/x` so you can use whitespace in your regex.

As the regex's for switching modes and capturing the layer number are mutually exclusive, you can let the other checks happen after a check succeeds - just be aware that if future changes result in overlapping cases, you need to do a `next` when one of the regex succeeds.

Finally, [List::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) is a core module so, you might as well grab the [max function](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#max) from it;

```
use v5.12;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw( max );

my @num ;
my $scanning = 0;
while (<>) {
    $scanning = 1  if /PIN vcc/ ;
    $scanning = 0  if /END vcc/ ;
    next unless $scanning ;
    push @num, $1  if /Layer \s+ m (\d+) /x ;
}
say "Max layer number found: ", max(@num) ;
```

Comment: The `if (/PIN vcc/../END vcc/) {` notation skips lines before a line containing `PIN vcc` (even if they contain 'Layer' lines), and also skips lines after `END vcc` (even if they contain 'Layer' lines).  There can be multiple blocks with the begin/end markers; they'll all end up being treated the same, I believe (that is, as if they were all part of a single big block).

Comment: Ahh - now I see.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler. you are right . the input source i pasted is a repeated unit from a file. The file that i am referring is LEF file by the way

Comment: i m trying but i'm am not sure how to integrate all of the suggestion into my codes :( . i did try out suggestion by @Сухой27 as her's is without while() . but the output is not what i want in my mind. let me update with more code/details. would like your kind help again :(

Comment: The default separating value (stored in `$,`) when you print any list - whether it's contained in an array or not - is indeed the empty string.  However, that's not what the OP was doing.  His code shows `print "@num";`, not `print @num;`.  When interpolating an array, the default separating value (stored in `$"`) is the string containing a single space character.  Unless the OP futzed with `$"` elsewhere in his code, `print "@num";` should have printed all the elements of the array, separated by a space.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply use `sort` function for to do it.

```
my @values ;
while (<DATA>) 
{    
       push (@values , $1) if (/Layer\s+m(\d+)\s;/);
}
my ($max) = sort{$b <=> $a} @values ;
print "$max\n";

__DATA__
Pin vcc
aaaa
bbbb
Port
  Layer m3 ;
END
CCC
DDD
Port 
  Layer m1 ;
END
EEE
FFF
Port
  Layer m0 ;
END
```

use `sort` function and store the first result into list contain the variable `$max`.

Answer (score 0):

```
my @data = <DATA> ;
my @num ;

foreach (@data) {
 push @num, $1 if /Layer\s+m(\S+)/ ;
} 
# home made max() - sorts an anonymous array and prints the last element
print [ sort { $a <=> $b } @num ]->[-1] , "\n" ;

__DATA__
Pin vcc
aaaa
bbbb
Port
  Layer m2 ;
END
CCC
DDD
Port 
  Layer m1 ;
END
EEE
FFF
Port
  Layer m0 ;
END
END vcc
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` to fetch numbers from file. `sort` the number and get maximum number.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $max = (sort{$b <=> $a }map{/Layer\s+m(\d+)/} <DATA>)[0];
print $max,"\n";

__DATA__
Pin vcc
aaaa
bbbb
Port
  Layer m3 ;
END
CCC
DDD
Port 
  Layer m1 ;
END
EEE
FFF
Port
  Layer m0 ;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to store all values if you're looking only for max value; and second, print the max value after the loop is over,

```
my $max = "-inf";
if (/PIN vcc/ .. /END vcc/) {
    $max = $1 if /LAYER\s+m(\S+)/ and $max < $1;
}

# ..
print $max, "\n";
```

Comment: hi Сухой27, would you explain to me what does this mean ? and $max < $1;

Comment: @TerryChengFeiYang `$max` starts with infinite negative value, and later it checks `$1` (which is capturing group of `(\S+)`) whether it is greater than `$max`